# Angularjs validation not working on copy-paste

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angular-material

I'm trying to create a US based phone number validation `###-###-####`, Using ng-pattern and tel-Mask directive..

If I do simple copy-paste `1234567890`, it works fine but and

When copy-paste a valid phone number and remove it,
And again copy-paste then it given error..

Here is working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9xrx87mw/1/

Comment: You remove the hyphens, and the pattern does not support values without them. Make them optional, [`ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4,5}$/"`](https://jsfiddle.net/9xrx87mw/2/)

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew, It works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JS code, you remove the hyphens from the number, and the pattern *requires* the hyphens to be present. Make them optional and use

```
ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4,5}$/" 
                       ^         ^
```

See the [updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9xrx87mw/2/).

The displayed values are rebuilt later, so the `?` quantifiers that allow matching 1 or 0 occurrences of the quantified subpattern will work as expected.

Comment: First of thanks for above.. But when I enter valid phone number and click outside the box(blur event) and again try to enter something extra(alphabets or none numerical letter) it given error, Can you suggest a solution.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to check that part, but it seems to be related to how and when the string is passed to the regex, and that is already making the question too broad.  Just keep in mind that once you remove the hyphens, they must be optional in the pattern.